# Norwegian wealth tax on money owed to the tax office?

Tags: norway, wealth-tax

I work and live in Norway, and pay the income tax according to the standard rules. I got paid part of my bonus in shares, gross (without witholding fractional shares for income tax). I sold the shares and put away an appropriate % of the money into a savings account towards the income tax on the bonus. I will submit my tax return and pay the tax I owe in early 2022. However, Norway also levies a 0.85% wealth tax on the cash you hold on the 31 December of the relevant tax year. But part of that cash isn't really mine - it's money I owe Norway for the income tax. Do I also need to pay the wealth tax on that money?

Comment: That you owe that money is not the same as "not your money". It becomes "not your money" when you actually pay it out.

Comment: Yeah, I get that logic, but wasn't sure about the wealth tax treatment because you do get to deduct the money owed to the bank via the mortgage from the value of your house when calculating the wealth tax on it.

Comment: That's probably because Norway's definition of someone's wealth is the same as someone's net worth; that is: assets minus liabilities. The house is the asset. The mortgage is the liability.

Comment: I see. Turns out it's super easy to avoid paying the wealth tax on the money I set aside for income tax liabilities. I just reported the extra income to Skatteetaten and they sent me an invoice for the extra tax :) I'm amazed at the user-friendliness, in the UK it was a lot more complicated.